# Installing Paypal PHP SDK using composer and PuTTY

Tags: php, paypal, sdk, putty

Using PuTTY (I don't have root access to the server) I typed `composer require "paypal/rest-api-sdk-php:*"` as it said here: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki/Installation-Composer and it works fine, but how can I install it into directory `d/pp/` instead of root? I tried `d/pp/composer require "paypal/rest-api-sdk-php:*"` but that's not it

I already downloaded the SDK directly but it seems not to work properly so I want to try it this way and I want to learn it anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a file named composer.json in your root directory and add the following code to it:

```
{
  "config": {
    "vendor-dir": "d/pp"
  },
  "require": {
    "paypal/rest-api-sdk-php": "*"
  }
}
```

now run composer install.

The config parameter lets you define configurations for your packages.

The vendor-dir directive sets the package's destination.

If you want to add more packages - in your require:{} section just add those too and run `composer update`.

Comment: Change `"paypal/rest-api-sdk-php": "*",` to `"paypal/rest-api-sdk-php": ">=1.10"`

Comment: It's still the same and:  Expected: 'STRING' - It appears you have an extra trailing comma

Comment: Ok I removed the 2 commas in json which are wrong and it works fine thanks :D